# How to reduce image size without changing dimension of image?

Tags: xcode, image

The size of an image is about 1.5MB. It's too big. I'm going to convert the image to pdf file. How to reduce the size of image (width, height is same)? Or which way to change pdf file size after convert the image to pdf?

Currently I'm using the code below:

```
img = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.01f)];
```

but the size of image is still large.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the the problem is with the size of the image and not with the size of the "image in the PDF"?

You say that the size is 1,5MB, but when? Before or after `[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.01f)];` line?

You are using an high compression ratio, so if the size is 1,5MB AFTER...your image has, probably, a very very high resolution. 
Compression can't do miracles ;-)

However I suspect that your problem is in the PDF conversion, so check the image size of the image after the `[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.01f)];` line and let me know

Comment: I get the image after capture from iPhone4 ->it's is 1.5MB. After using the code: [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.01f)]; it is near 1MB ->still big. The conversion pdf file has same size with image size.

Comment: Sorry, added the previous comment before reading your update. It seems strange, your compression ratio is high...can you post a sample image so I try to compress it?

Comment: exactly 819KB after running that line.

Comment: you can try with any image from photo library on the iPhone.

Comment: I said to post your image because it seems very strange to me: in my case, starting from a 1,8MB JPEG resulted in a 180KB final image, using 0.01f compression ratio. What is the resolution? Just to be sure, we are talking about each image you compress, not a particular one, right?

Comment: I've checked again. The image size is very small after using 0.01f compression ratio. The actual problem is after converting an image to pdf file the pdf file size is too big.

Comment: Ok, it's what I suspected. How are you doing the conversion? Which components and code are you using to convert in PDF? I suggest you to update your original question with this details :-)